# C++ LinkedList Node to store generic objects

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, nodes

If you have a generic Node that store ints, float or Objects of a certain type, how could you store generic objects in your node?

```
typedef struct node{
      Dog data;
      node* next;
  }*nodePtr;
```

This node stores Dog objects... how could I store generic objects?

One idea I have is to have Dog objects and all other objects inherit from a more general Object class. *Good way to go other than using templates?*

Comment: Do you mean you want a Node containing a Dog to point to a Node containing a Cat?

Comment: You tagged the question with C++, but the code looks like C. Just want to confirm: C or C++?

Comment: Create a bass class with just a next pointer and an object type indicator, then use inheritance to create classes based on this class.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts almost exactly.

Comment: C++. I realized typdefs are C, but still works in C++.

Comment: @user3308043 - Read the paper that none other than Mr. Stroustrup wrote on using the "universal object" approach you seem to like a lot:

http://www.stroustrup.com/ETAPS-corrected-draft.pdf

Comment: To whit: `"C++ does not provide a universal base class. I consider such a class an unnecessary implementation-oriented artifact that imposes avoidable space and time overheads. Also, a universal “Object” base encourages underspecified (overly general) interfaces that let errors that could be detected at compile time through to run time.  Typically, C++ uses parameterization where another language might use a common base class and require implicit or
explicit type conversion to determine the exact derived class."` -- Bjarne Stroustrup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One idea I have is to have Dog objects and all other objects inherit from a more general Object class. Good way to go?

**If the types all have something in common, create a common base type for them. If not, then don't.**

Don't make the types derive from a common base just because you want to store them all in the same container. You'd have it backwards. *If* you want to store all the types in the same container, they *should* have something in common already. Otherwise your container is just a sequence of bits. There would be nothing it could do that wouldn't be better done by separate containers for each type. For example, you couldn't iterate through the container and call a method on each element, because there wouldn't *be* a method that all the elements have!

You said,

> Great answer, but I'm looking to do it through OO principles.

One of the basic principles of OO, IMO, is that *all your classes should be meaningful*. This doesn't mean they have to correspond to concrete objects, or even contain any implementation, but they do have to at least contain some interface. A generic `Object` class in C++ is not meaningful. Don't create one.

Comment: I suppose I'll go with DataItem or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

C++ offers the `template<>` for generics:

```
template<typename T>
struct node {
    T data;
    node<T> *next;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'm looking to do it through OO principles.

Comment: C++ isn't Java.  The way you accomplish what you set out to do in C++ is to use a template.

Answer (score 2):

Make a template, like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T> *next;
};
```

A good resource to find information on templates can be e.g. the Wikipedia.